# Dynamically create a table with values from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a table that looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|                         | USD            |CAD   |
--------------------------------------------------
|Smallest Donation        | 100            |250   |
--------------------------------------------------
|Largest Donation         | 9200           |7600  |
--------------------------------------------------
|                                                 |
--------------------------------------------------
|Total Donation           | 12500          |11000 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

using the values from this object:

```jquery
perCurrency: {USD:{0:100, 1:200, 2:9200, 3:1500, 4:1500}, PHP:{0:250, 1:7600, 2:150, 3:3000}}
```

I have this code and it actually works, though I believe there's an easier and shorter way to this using only one loop.

```jquery
var numOfCurrency = Object.keys(perCurrency).length + 1;
var donation_table = '';
donation_table += '<table id="donation_table" class="table table-condensed">';
donation_table += '<tr><td style="font-weight:bold; width:160px">&nbsp;</td>';

$.each(perCurrency, function(index, value){
  donation_table += '<td width="150px">'+index+'</td>';
});

donation_table += '</tr><tr><td style="font-weight:bold; width:160px">Smallest Donation</td>';
$.each(perCurrency, function(index, value){
  var lowest = Infinity;
  $.each(value, function(k, v){
    if (v < lowest) lowest = v;
  });
  donation_table  += '<td>'+lowest+'</td>';
});

donation_table += '</tr><tr><td style="font-weight:bold; width:160px">Largest Donation</td>';
$.each(perCurrency, function(index, value){
  var highest = 0;
  $.each(value, function(k, v){
    if (v > highest) highest = v;
  });
  donation_table += '<td>'+highest+'</td>';
});

donation_table += '</tr><tr><td colspan="'+numOfCurrency+'">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style="font-weight:bold; width:160px">Total Donation</td>';
$.each(perCurrency, function(index, value){
  var total = 0;
  $.each(value, function(k, v){
    total = total + v;
  });
  donation_table += '<td>'+total+'</td>';
});

donation_table += '</tr></table>';

$("#giving_capacity").html(donation_table);
```

I am trying to put this table in a div with an id `#giving_capacity`.

Comment: i dont think condensing everything to one loop will make things run that much faster - looks like what you are doing is good.

Comment: `numOfCurrency` and `donationTable` appear `undefined` utilizing piece at OP. Also, at `perCuererrency` object, `PHP` is named property, instead of `CAD`. Adjusted at jsfiddle, see http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/CMwM2/

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite in my style with only loop. It maybe easier to read.

```
perCurrency = {
  USD: { 0:100, 1:200, 2:9200, 3:1500, 4:1500 },
  CAD: { 0:250, 1:7600, 2:150, 3:3000 }
};
var numOfCurrency = Object.keys(perCurrency).length + 1;
var donation_table;
donation_table = $('<table>').attr('id', 'donation_table').addClass('table table-condensed'));

$.each(perCurrency, function(index, currency) {
  var lowestInCurrency  = Infinity,
      highestInCurrency = 0,
      totalInCurrency   = 0;
  $.each(currency, function(k, v){
    totalInCurrency = totalInCurrency + v;
    if (v < lowestInCurrency) lowestInCurrency = v;
    if (v > highestInCurrency) highestInCurrency = v;
  });

  donation_table.append(
    $('<tr>').append(
      $('<td>').css('font-weight', 'bold').css('width', '160px').html('&nbsp;')
    ).append(
      $('<td>').css('width', '150px').text(index)
    )
  ).append(
    $('<tr>').append(
      $('<td>').css('font-weight', 'bold').css('width', '160px').text('Smallest Donation')
    ).append(
      $('<td>').text(lowestInCurrency)
    )
  ).append(
    $('<tr>').append(
      $('<td>').css('font-weight', 'bold').css('width', '160px').text('Largest Donation')
    ).append(
      $('<td>').text(highestInCurrency)
    )
  ).append(
    $('<tr>').append(
      $('<td>').attr('colspan', numOfCurrency).html('&nbsp;')
    )
  ).append(
    $('<tr>').append(
      $('<td>').css('font-weight', 'bold').css('width', '160px').text('Total Donation')
    ).append(
      $('<td>').text(totalInCurrency)
    )
  );
});

$("#giving_capacity").html(donation_table);
```